# What is redundant in my insert-method?

Tags: c#

This is my recursive insert-method for a linked list:

```
public static MyLinkedList recursiveInsert(int value, ref MyLinkedList list)
{
    if (list == null)
    {
        return new MyLinkedList(value, null);
    {
    else
    {
        list.next = recursiveInsert(value, ref list.next);
        return list;
    }
}
```

I'm learning about C# and recursion at the moment, and my question is: what is redundant on the following line?

```
list.next = recursiveInsert(value, ref list.next);
```

Comment: OK, easy question to get you started: what is it that makes you think anything is "redundant"?

Comment: Not enough info to diagnose.  Redundant means it's not necessary, but state is always necessary in recursion.  You're passing state, so it's not redundant.

Comment: Not related to redundancy, but for lists with many elements, calling *recursiveInsert* (which is rather a listAppend) runs the risk of exhausting the call stack (i.e., recursion running "too deep").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other from some issues mentioned in the the comments, what is redundant is that you reassign the already assigned nodes in the list. The following should be sufficient, because you're already using the `ref` parameter (which also is not recommended, but I understand that this is just for practice):

```
public static void recursiveInsert(int value, ref MyLinkedList list)
{
    if (list == null)
    {
        list = new MyLinkedList(value, null);
    }
    else
    {
        recursiveInsert(value, ref list.next);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was after! Thanks!